# Ruby something wrong with validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I am new in Ruby. I have form which creates new appointment (I save there `doctor_id`, `patient_id`, `date`, `time`) I have also schedules in database (`doctor_id` in schedule is `FK`, there are `dayofweek`, `starttime`, `endtime`) and now I want to check if doctor is available in chosen day and time and if there are no appointment with this date and time. If I can't add and error message. MY PROBLEM is I get error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in AppointmentsController#create

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: schedules.doctor: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "schedules"  WHERE "schedules"."doctor" = 1 AND "schedules"."dzien_tygodnia" = 3 AND (poczatek_pracy < '2014-06-18 08:53:00.000000' and koniec_pracy > '2014-06-18 08:53:00.000000')
```

In schedule and appointment doctor_id is FK!

Translate for your better understanding:

```
-dzien_tygodnia - day_of_the_week;
-data_wizyty - visit_date;
-godzina_wizyty - visit_time;
-poczatek_pracy - start_working;
-koniec_pracy - end_working.
```

My `_form.html.erb`:

```
    <%= form_for(@appointment) do |f| %>
  <% if @appointment.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@appointment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this appointment from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @appointment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :data_wizyty %><br />
  <%=
    options = { start_year: 2.year.from_now.year,
                end_year: 2013,
                include_blank: true,
                default: nil }
    f.date_select :data_wizyty, options
  %>
  <!--<input type="text" data-behaviour='datepicker' :data_wizyty > -->
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :godzina_wizyty %><br />
    <%= f.time_select :godzina_wizyty %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :doctor_id, :value => Doctor.find(session[:current_doctor_id2]).id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :patient_id, :value => Patient.find(session[:current_patient_id]).id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag "Utworz wizyte" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

`appointment.rb`:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :doctor_id, uniqueness: { scope: [:data_wizyty, :godzina_wizyty], message: 'Ten termin jest juz zajety!' }
  validate :doctor_is_scheduled

  attr_accessible :data_wizyty, :doctor_id, :godzina_wizyty, :notatka, :objawy_choroby, :patient_id



    belongs_to :patient
    belongs_to :doctor
    belongs_to :schedule
    belongs_to :refferal

    has_many :employees

  def doctor_is_scheduled
    if Schedule.where(doctor: doctor, dzien_tygodnia: data_wizyty.wday)
               .where('poczatek_pracy < ? and koniec_pracy > ?', godzina_wizyty, godzina_wizyty).empty?
      self.errors.add(:doctor, message: 'nie pracuje w tym terminie!')
    end
  end


end
```

Controller/create action in appointment:

```
def create
    @appointment = Appointment.new(params[:appointment])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @appointment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @appointment, notice: 'Appointment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @appointment, status: :created, location: @appointment }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @appointment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Could you tell me which files should be included?

Comment: Can you post your `create action` of your `AppointmentsController`?

Comment: I think it takes doctor as FK, but doctor_id is FK. I don't know where to change this in appointment.rb

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to change your where clause because it's trying to use a doctor column on the schedules table which doesn't exist

`Schedule.where(doctor_id: doctor, dzien_tygodnia: data_wizyty.wday)`

Update:

Ok so you're using `@schedules` in new but if it fails it doesn't have that anymore so you need to add it to create e.g.

```
def create
    @appointment = Appointment.new(params[:appointment])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @appointment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @appointment, notice: 'Appointment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @appointment, status: :created, location: @appointment }
      else
        format.html do 
          @schedules = Schedule.all #or whatever query you do for new
          render action: "new"
        end
        format.json { render json: @appointment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Ok, it's OK, but now I get error:
NoMethodError in Appointments#create

Showing D:/Studia/Bazy Danych/Projekt/Implementacja/ZOZ/app/views/appointments/new.html.erb where line #52 raised:

undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Is that this line `<% @appointment.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>`?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to put code in comments :D
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #52):

49:    </thead>
50: 
51: <tbody>
52: <% @schedules.each do |schedule| %>
53:   <tr>
54:     <td><%= schedule.dzien_tygodnia %></td>
55:     <td><%= schedule.poczatek_pracy %></td>

Comment: Aaa , it's where I show doctor Schedule for week on that page

Comment: Ok, I made progress but now when I choose good date and time I get "Not working in that time" Also after this error all schedules are displayed, not only belongs to choosen doctor

Comment: Ok, second problem I solved but still first with doctor not working :(

Comment: `Schedule.where(doctor: doctor, dzien_tygodnia: data_wizyty.wday)
               .where('poczatek_pracy < ? and koniec_pracy > ?', godzina_wizyty, godzina_wizyty).empty?` What does this actually do?  Currently your code says `if` it's empty then add the error, maybe you want `unless`

Comment: Always said that "He is not working" even if it is not true :)